# Riverpod provider with fetch-once async call

Tags: flutter, riverpod, flutter-riverpod

I am using Riverpod 2 provider to get value from a Future Provider as shown below.

```dart
@riverpod
Future<AppUser> fetchCurrentUser(FetchCurrentUserRef ref) async {
  // usersRef is the Firebase ODM refence here
  final ref = await usersRef.doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid).get();
  return ref.data!;
}
```

I use the above provider using `ref.watch(fetchCurrentUserProvider).when()` to display in the UI. It all works fine.

I understand that the values will be cached for next time use.

What I am looking for is to avoid the async `when()` *everytime* when consuming it. How can I make the initial future call to happen only once so that I can use the `ref` without worrying about the async nature.

Still, I want to use Riverpod for state management, but avoid dealing with loading, error and when actions of a future provider.

Whenever I want to use it, I will be getting the value directly, somehting like `ref.watch(fetchCurrentUserProvider).avatar_url`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having to use `when` everywhere is not something you should fight. Everywhere you uses the result, there's a change it's in loading or error state. So you should handle those

If you're absolutely certain your future is resolved, you can do `ref.watch(provider).requireValue.whatever`